# Universal abelian cover of knot complement

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, knot-theory

[image]

Here author remarks that $Y_{i}$ closure is homeomorphic to $S^{3}-(K \cup N) $ which we can see as $S^{3}-K$ cut along M with two boundary components homeomorphic to M(interior) and we can then think X tilda as gluing of these later copies.
Can someone shed light on this remark, ( I don't see the homeomorphism and the equivalent construction of X tilda).

Comment: Why did you redact the chapter and page number? It is good practice to let people know what you are referring to.  This is Rolfsen, "Knots and Links," page 129.

Comment: Okay, I just thought it may create confusion while reading the construction.

Answer (score 0):

Write $X_K^\infty$ for the infinite cyclic cover of the knot exterior $X_K:=S^3 \setminus \nu (K)$ and $Y:=\bigcup\limits_{i=-\infty}^\infty Y_i$. We must show that $Y \cong X_K^\infty$. Both are covering spaces of $X_K$ and so we use covering space theory: we will get the required isomorphism if the two covers define the same subgroup of $\pi_1(X_K)$.

Here, recall that the subgroup of $\pi_1(B)$ determined by a covering $p \colon E \to B$ is $p_*(\pi_1(E))$.
This subgroup equals the set of loops in $B$ that lifts to loops in $E$ (I am avoiding mentioning base points, but there are fixed).
Recall from covering space theory that assigning to a covering $E \to B$ the subgroup $p_*(\pi_1(E))$ gives a bijection between covering spaces of $B$ and subgroups of $\pi_1(B)$ (here I am being loose on the precise statement, but all of this is in Hatcher).
For short, let me refer to $p_*(\pi_1(E))$ as ``the group of the cover $p \colon E\to B$".

So we have reduced the problem to showing that the loops in $X_K$ that lifts to $X_K^\infty$ coincide with the loops in $X_K$ that lift to $Y$.
Let's first look at the group of $X_K^\infty \to X_K$ and then at the group of $Y \to X_K$

Let's recall the definition of $X_K^\infty$.
This is the cover of $X_K$ corresponding to the subgroup $\ker(\operatorname{ab} \colon \pi_1(X_K) \to H_1(X_K) \cong \mathbb{Z})$.
Therefore the group of this cover equals $\ker(\operatorname{ab})$, i.e. it consists of those loops $\gamma \subset X_K$ with $\ell k(\gamma,K)=0$, i.e. those $\gamma$ such that $M \cdot \gamma=0$, where $M$ is your Seifert surface.

But now if you look at $Y=\bigcup\limits_{i=-\infty}^\infty Y_i$, you see that is also the condition for a loop $\gamma \subset X_K$ to lift a loop in $Y$: if the lifted curve starts going to one side or another of $Y$, it will cross a lift of $M$ and if you want a loop, it had better come back; in total you must therefore have $M \cdot \gamma=0$.

Comment: That is fine. But I wanted to see more concrete homeomorphism between the two spaces constructed. As I mentioned, the Rolfsen book says $\bar{ Y_i}$ is homeomorphic to $X-(K \cup M)$. I am more interested in seeing this homeomorphism.